Хранение картинок в Discord
Есть кто разбирается во внутренней кухне Дискорда?
Просто написал бота для него, но вот с картинками, оказывается, какая то беда. Бот получает ссылку на картинку, которая в интернете, ее и печатает.
Если я потом в самом хранилище картинки ее изменю, то бот, как ни в чем ни бывало, продолжит печатать ту картинку, которая уже есть в Дискорде в прошлых сообщениях (и которая изменена в интернете). Я сначала решил, что уже загруженные картинки остаются где-то в самом Дискорде, откуда он их потом берет, если встречает ту же самую ссылку. Но не тут то было....
Если я картинку в самом хранилище удалю, то Дискорд продолжит ее отображать в уже опубликованных сообщениях на моем устройстве. А на других устройствах при просмотре ничего отображаться не будет.
Это вообще как работает? Есть кто разбирается?

Понимаю, что отвечаю поздно, но всё же: насколько я знаю, всё что загружается в дс загружается на сервера дискорда и хранятся там. Насчёт отображения после удаления: хз если честно, такого не должно быть, если я правильно понимаю что и где вы удаляете
